# MySQL Creating Unnecessary Sort Index When an Aggregate Query is a Subquery

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, group-by, subquery, aggregate

I have a complicated aggregate query, using the functions SUM and GROUP_CONCAT, that starts returning results in a reasonable amount of time by itself. But when this query is wrapped in another query, in the form of: `SELECT * FROM ([original_aggregate_query]) sq;`, it becomes incredibly slow as it gets stuck in the "Creating sort index" status. I cannot prevent the query from being wrapped as such because the BI tool we use does this automatically. Is there a general way to optimize large aggregate queries for use within subqueries?

I believe this part of the MySQL documentation may be related to my issue.

> It is possible to disable merging by using in the subquery any constructs that prevent merging, although these are not as explicit in their effect on materialization.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-table-optimization.html

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Condolences.  Tools are supposed to help users, but sometimes they just get in the way.  Does it allow you to provide 'raw' SQL?  I might have some serious clues if you provide the full query plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It may be possible to, say, a dd a composite index that would avoid the problem.

Comment: Have you considered posting your actual query that is getting stuck with "Creating sort index"?  The real query is your best documentation when you want someone to assist.